# Myfaces2 and Tomahawk2 extension filter

Tags: javascript, jsf, filter, tomahawk

I've been struggling on an issue for days and I don't know what to do to have it work.
I try to use Tomahawk components that works with javascript... And I always get a javascript error : "xxx is not defined" (xxx=orgApacheMyfacesPopup for instance).

As far as I know it seems to be an extension filter issue : the server can't serve the .js containing the needed definitions... But I can't see what's wrong.

I've just done a little project with eclipse from scratch and I always get the error.

The steps I followed were :

1. create a new Web Application Project (targetting Tomcat 6, adding support for JSF2.0 downloading Myfaces2)
2. Download and copy jsstl-api-1.2.jar and jstl-impl-1.2.jar to WEB-INF/lib
3. Download Tomahawk for JSF2 and copy the jars to WEB-INF/lib
4. Modify web.xml (as delivered after)
5. Create index.xhtml (as delivered after)

My web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>TestTomahawk</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
      <param-name>uploadMaxFileSize</param-name>
      <param-value>20m</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  </filter-mapping>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MyFacesExtensionsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/myFacesExtensionResource/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My index.xhtml file :

```
    <html   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
        xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
        >
    <body>
        <h:form>
            <t:popup    styleClass="popup"
                    closePopupOnExitingElement="false"
                        closePopupOnExitingPopup="false"
                        displayAtDistanceX="0"
                        displayAtDistanceY="0"
                        >
                <h:outputText value="test popup" />
                <f:facet name="popup">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText     value="foo"/>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
            </t:popup>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone ansderstand why it doesn't work ?

PS : I tried with Tomecat 7 and it doesn't work better...

Thanks

---

Nobody ?
Has anybody make Myfaces2 and tomahawk2 work with javascript and xhtml ?
Do somebody know where to find samples for it ?
Samples on MyFaces website seem to target JSF 1.1 and JSP-like pages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `<h:head>` instead of `<head>` in order to auto-include JavaScript (and CSS) files which are specific to JSF components. Additionally, you should preferably also replace `<body>` by `<h:body>`.

The proper Facelet template should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">
    <h:head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1>Body</h1>
    </h:body>
</html>
```